# XSLT to XML where Attribute matches a pattern

Tags: xslt

I am new to XSLT, please excuse if my question is too trivial.

I need to transform the below xml

```
<annotation text="Australia" f:abc.location.adm1="AU.00" f:aliases="AUSTRALIAN" f:abc.location.population="21515754" f:abc.location.id="2077456"/>
```

To name value pair. Need to match part of the attribute i.e convert any attributes of the form "**f:abc**....".

For Example the output should be.

```
<property><name>location.adm1</name><value>AU.00</value></property>
<property><name>population</name><value>21515754</value></property>
<property><name>location.id</name><value>2077456</value></property>
```

Tried the code

```
<xsl:template match="t:annotation[@f:abc*]">
```

but no success, Request to please guide me on how to create my .xls to get the desired output xml.

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can test for those attributes by doing this:

```
<xsl:template match="t:annotation[@f:*[starts-with(local-name(), 'abc.')]]">
```

And then you can make use of the template with something like this:

```
<xsl:template match="t:annotation[@f:*[starts-with(local-name(), 'abc.')]]">
   <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@f:*[starts-with(local-name(), 'abc.')]" />
   </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="@f:*[starts-with(local-name(), 'abc.')]">
   <property>
      <name>
         <xsl:value-of select="substring-after(local-name(), 'abc.')" />
      </name>
      <value>
         <xsl:value-of select="." />
      </value>
   </property>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot JLRishe, this exactly does what I required.